# How can I see questions I've asked during commitment phase?

Tags: support, area51

I asked a question when this site (linguistics) was still in commitment phase. However, it didn't got answer, since it wasn't appropriate at that time. Now, I just don't know what the question was. I've forgotten it.

However, it doesn't appear in my profile and I don't know where should I search for it.

How can I see it?

Comment: do you mean proposed questions?

Answer (score 4):

If you go to Area 51 you can click the links to find your activity.

I'll edit the answer with the exact steps...

- Go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- Click on [your username](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/40870/saeed-neamati) in the top right
- On the middle of the right side of the page click on the "[activity](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/40870/saeed-neamati?tab=activity)" tab

From here I can see you've proposed a few questions for other proposed sites but not actually for this one:

- Theoretical Art: Do artists like to show their art to others psychologically? Do they enjoy being praised because of their artworks?
- [etymology: Where the word “police” comes from?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34046/etymology-where-the-word-police-comes-from/34047#34047)
- [Esperanto Language & Usage: Can we regard Esperanto as the most phonetic language?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13148/esperanto-language-usage-can-we-regard-esperanto-as-the-most-phonetic-language/34043#34043)

The question in the closed etymology proposal would belong on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) rather than here on Linguistics.

The question on Esperanto may or may not belong here since some linguists do not take constructed languages seriously (I am not one of them though).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean proposed questions during the *definition* phase? They normally don't get answers, because they are there just for defining what's on and off topic here.

Anyway, alternatively to what @hippietrail suggested. you can find them in the proposal's area 51 page, example: [Linguistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics), then get to the [definition tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673?phase=definition) and find all those questions there.

Comment: I don't think he was expecting answers there but wanted to remember what questions he asked so he could ask them again here on the site now that it exists.